# How do I covert Jul,2020 to JUL,2020 using data time formatter?

Tags: scala

I am using this.

```
val thisMonth = YearMonth.now()
val lastMonth = thisMonth.minusMonths(1) // to get the last month
val last12thMonth = thisMonth.minusMonths(12) // to get the Last 12th month
val monthYearFormatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM,yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
val lastMonthinWords = lastMonth.format(monthYearFormatter)
```

I am getting the output as Jun,2020, but I need my output to be JUN,2020.

Comment: Can't you just capitalize the string? Or are you looking for an "official" approach?

Comment: Why don't you try lastMonth.format(monthYearFormatter).toUpperCase(). that should solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah, `DateTimeFormatter` doesn't have a built-in way of doing this.  You just gotta convert it separately, as per MadAboutProgramming's comment.

Comment: @PiRocks, yes I was looking for an official approach, but I guess it is fine, I'll just use .toUpperCase().

Comment: @MadAboutProgramming....yes I could do that, But I guess there is no other way as Dawood mentioned.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem...thanks for updating me. I guess I should go with .toUpperCase()....any way thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The month of March prints as “Mar,” so you may want to convert the result to upper-case or lower-case:

```
scala> val mon = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM").format(cal.getTime()).toUpperCase
mon: String = MAR

scala> val mon = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM").format(cal.getTime()).toLowerCase
mon: String = mar
```

In your case it's pretty simple

```
lastMonth.format(monthYearFormatter).toUpperCase().
```

**Reference :**

You can refer below link you will get some idea.

https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-get-current-month-as-number-or-string/